# How to get Odata Next Link from the returned JSON object using angular $http service

Tags: .net, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have implemented Odata query syntax for my web api. I am successfully able to return only the first 10 results and the link for the further results. However I am unable to extract this link from the JSON object that is returned by the server using my angularjs front end.

Say the server is responding as follows:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:60497/odata/$metadata#tables","value":[
    {
      "id":001,"name":"abc"
    },{
      "id":002,"name":"pqr"
    },{
      "id":003,"name":"xyz"
    },{
      .
      .
      .
  ],"odata.nextLink":"http://localhost:60497/odata/tables?$skip=10"
}
```

Now I am displaying the data by using the success method of $http by assigning the returned data to a variable and using ng-repeat. I am assigning it as follows:

```
.success(function(data)){
  $scope.foo = data.value;
}
```

However when I try to access the next link using:

```
$scope.link = data.odata.nextLink;
```

within the success method it gives me an error. What am I missing over here? How else can I access the link returned? Is there any other method to implement server side paging?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, more or less. I guess it has got to do with JavaScript objects and how their properties are referred to. The reference

```
data.odata.nextLink
```

would mean there is a property "odata" with a sub-property/field "nextLink". This is not the case, "odata.nextLink" is the name of the property. I don't know why OData is like this.

I got the contents of this property by using a string reference i.e.

```
data['odata.nextLink']
```

Don't know if there is some drawback, but seems to work...

Answer (score 3):

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;     
    [JsonProperty("@odata.nextLink")]
    public string nextPage { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work using

```
theReturnedObject['@odata.nextLink']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the odata values should have an @ in front of them. I'm not sure how your implementation handles that character but it should be a valid prefix.

The issue I am running into is that some providers use the full path and some only use a relative path from the service endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The C# method that I devised for use with the **Microsoft Graph API** is as follows.

```
private static string GetNextLink ( JObject pjobjResult )
{
    JProperty jtLastToken = ( JProperty ) pjobjResult.Last;

    if ( jtLastToken.Name.Equals ( @"@odata.nextLink" ) )
    {
        return jtLastToken.Value.ToString ( );
    }   // TRUE (There is at least one more page.) block, if ( jtLastToken.Name.Equals ( @"@odata.nextLink" ) )
    else
    {
        return SpecialStrings.EMPTY_STRING;
    }   // FALSE (The current page is the last one.) block, if ( jtLastToken.Name.Equals ( @"@odata.nextLink" ) )
}   // private static string GetNextLink
```

In the above method, **SpecialStrings.EMPTY_STRING** is the name of a true constant that I use in lieu of **string.Empty**.

A similar method should work for **PowerShell**, too.